# Search in array of object for a string like

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wrote this code in typescript that searches an object not strictly equal in a list of object:

```
list = list.filter(
  x => (x.surname + ' ' + x.name)
          .trim()
          .toLowerCase()
          .search(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
```

So if I want to search Alex and type only `al`, `alex` will be displayed as valid result.

When I moved this code in a javascript codebase it was totally broken, error about search, trim() etc.

There is a way to achieve this result without writing loops over loops?

Comment: take a look at regex for javascript

Comment: i want to avoid regex

Comment: why do you want to avoid it ?

Comment: Not everyone wants to use regex voodoo

Comment: So you're saying you have an error message and you didn't paste it in your question?

Comment: Given an example array of objects with name and surname props, the code shown works as intended. So we need more information. So many things could be wrong: Eg. You're testing in IE11 or a different browser that does not recognize the arrow. `list` is a constant and can't be reassigned. `list` is not an array. `filter`is not declared or is not a string. You're running a build system that changes this code into invalid code. So many possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine, and it works for the case that you described, except for [old browsers that don't support arrow functions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).

Note also that [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) will create a **regex** from the string that you pass into it, which might give unexpected results if e.g. you pass it a simple period `.`; if you don't want that, then you'd better use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Here is a demo of both approaches:

```js
function findUsingSearch(list, filter) {
  return list.filter(
    x => (x.surname + ' ' + x.name)
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()
    .search(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
}

function findUsingIndexOf(list, filter) {
  return list.filter(
    x => (x.surname + ' ' + x.name)
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
}

var data = [{ surname: 'Alex', name: 'Foo' }, { surname: 'Oleg', name: 'Bar' }];

console.log('*** findUsingSearch:')
console.log(findUsingSearch(data, 'al'));
console.log(findUsingSearch(data, 'ol'));
console.log(findUsingSearch(data, 'ul'));
console.log(findUsingSearch(data, '.'));

console.log('*** findUsingIndexOf:')
console.log(findUsingIndexOf(data, 'al'));
console.log(findUsingIndexOf(data, 'ol'));
console.log(findUsingIndexOf(data, 'ul'));
console.log(findUsingIndexOf(data, '.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm reading the question correctly, you have an array of objects like this:

```
const people = [
  { name: 'Dave', surname: 'Smith' },
  { name: 'Stevie', surname: 'Wonder' },
  { name: 'Alex', surname: 'Winter' }
];
```

And you want to search the list looking for a person that matches a specific string partial (call it `searchString`)? This should do it:

```
const result = people.find(
  person => {
    const name = person.name.toLowerCase();
    const surname = person.surname.toLowerCase();

    if (`${name}${surname}.includes(searchString.toLowerCase()) {
      return person;
    }
  }
);
```

This can be wrapped into a single line; it looks a bit unwieldy in a SO snippet, but here it is:

```
const result = people.find(person => `${person.name.toLowerCase()}${person.surname.toLowerCase()}`.includes(searchString.toLowerCase()));
```

If you want to return an array of all matching results, replace `find` with `filter`:

```
const result = people.filter(person => `${person.name.toLowerCase()}${person.surname.toLowerCase()}`.includes(searchString.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: Search for _A_ person or _ANY_ person? `find()` will only return the first match.

Comment: I didn't take that away from the question, but you are of course correct. I'll add an edit.